# OpenCL: Downsampling with bilinear interpolation

Tags: c++, opencl

I've a problem with downsampling image with bilinear interpolation. I've read almost all relevant articles on stackoverflow and searched around in google, trying to solve or at least to find the problem in my OpenCL kernel. This is my [main source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) for the theory. After I implemented this code in OpenCL:

```
__kernel void downsample(__global uchar* image, __global uchar* outputImage, __global int* width, __global int* height, __global float* factor){

//image vector containing original RGB values
//outputImage vector containing "downsampled" RGB mean values
//factor - downsampling factor, downscaling the image by factor: 1024*1024 -> 1024/factor * 1024/factor

int r = get_global_id(0);
int c = get_global_id(1); //current coordinates
int oWidth = get_global_size(0);     
int olc, ohc, olr, ohr; //coordinates of the original image used for bilinear interpolation
int index; //linearized index of the point  
uchar q11, q12, q21, q22;
float accurate_c, accurate_r; //the exact scaled point
int k;

accurate_c = convert_float(c*factor[0]);
olc=convert_int(accurate_c);
ohc=olc+1;

if(!(ohc<width[0]))
ohc=olc;

accurate_r = convert_float(r*factor[0]);
olr=convert_int(accurate_r);
ohr=olr+1;

if(!(ohr<height[0]))
ohr=olr;

index= (c + r*oWidth)*3; //3 bytes per pixel
//Compute RGB values: take a central mean RGB values among four points 
for(k=0; k<3; k++){
    q11=image[(olc + olr*width[0])*3+k];
    q12=image[(olc + ohr*width[0])*3+k];
    q21=image[(ohc + olr*width[0])*3+k];
    q22=image[(ohc + ohr*width[0])*3+k];
    outputImage[index+k] = convert_uchar((q11*(ohc - accurate_c)*(ohr - accurate_r) + 
                                          q21*(accurate_c - olc)*(ohr - accurate_r) + 
                                          q12*(ohc - accurate_c)*(accurate_r - olr) +
                                          q22*(accurate_c - olc)*(accurate_r - olr)));
  }
}
```

The kernel works with factor = 2, 4, 5, 6 but not with factor = 3, 7 (I get missing pixels, and the image appears little bit skewed) whereas the "identical" code written in c++ works fine with all factor values. I cann't explain it to myself why that happens in opencl. I attach my full code project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDz0bAvvNvcMWp0UVhabjN5N0k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: A few comments on this.  First, the bounds checking looks suspicious.  If ohc > width, setting ohc to olc will not bring it in bounds.  So your input accesses are probably going way out-of-bounds.  This would not explain why 2, 4, 5, 6 work and 3, 7 do not.  But it seems to be a problem.  Also, it looks like a some of the things that are passed in buffers could be more efficiently passed as regular ints (width, height, factor).

Comment: 1. Bounds checking: you are right, I guess writing if(!(olc<width) and if(!(olr<height) maybe now it's correct. 2. I tried different images 1024*1024 512*512 720*720. First two have the same problems with same scaling factors as described above, whereas the last image has problems with 5,7. For now, my supposition is that the problem lies in dimensions of the image and maybe in particulary has something to do with dimension approximation that cuts off some RGB pixels values when it has to write back result on a new image .bmp file. That's all what I could find out, any other clues?

Comment: Hey!, That would be great if you could post your C++ code here. I am working on something similer in c++.

Comment: https://github.com/nico-mkhatvari/OpenCL